# Java GAE Task Queue CallNotFoundException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, task-queue

When trying to implement a push queue, I am getting the following error:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call taskqueue.BulkAdd in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
```

Within my servlet's `doPost()` method, here is my task:

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("rating-queue");
queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/addrating")
     .param("function", function)
     .param("user_id", Integer.toString(user_id))
     .param("item_id", Integer.toString(item_id))
     .param("is_user", Boolean.toString(isUser)));
```

In my `web.xml` file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AddRating</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.ExampleClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddRating</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addrating</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my queue.xml file in my WEB-INF folder:

```
<queue-entries>
    <queue>
        <name>default</name>
        <rate>5/s</rate>
    </queue>
    <queue>
        <name>rating-queue</name>
        <rate>5/s</rate>
    </queue>
</queue-entries>
```

I'm running my servlet locally. There are no task queues visible in my app engine console.

Comment: where did you configure your queue 'rating-queue'?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer see above edit to my original post

Comment: not sure if you have to define the default queue in your config file but I would propose to remove the queue.xml file and try touse instead QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue(). I am using only the default queue without any config file

Comment: @MichaelMeyer Originally I was using the default queue but that was also returning the same error. I switched to a custom queue to see if that made any difference, which it didn't. Is it possible that it's the particular App Engine API library that I'm using? Right now I'm using `com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.51` from Maven repository.

Comment: I am using 1.9.48

Comment: Did you solve this Issue? I am trying to Use TaskQueue from flexible-Environment in Java and get the same Error

Comment: @user2122552 I did actually. The problem is that task queues only work in the Standard Environment, not in the Flexible Environment. If you're using the Flexible Environment, you can possibly use [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/) instead.