# Java GAE Task Queue throws CallNotFoundException from Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, task-queue

I am running GAE under spring boot. I want to implement a push queue but keep getting:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't 
make API call taskqueue.BulkAdd in a thread that is neither the 
original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
```

At first I tried to add task in the rest controller like that:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

   @GetMapping("/taskqueues/testTaskQueue")
   public ResponseEntity testTaskQueue(@RequestParam String key) {

       Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
       queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/testTaskQueue")
            .param("key", key));

       return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
   }
}
```

Next I tried defining a servlet in spring boot that way:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<Enqueue> exampleServletBean() {
    ServletRegistrationBean<Enqueue> bean = new 
    ServletRegistrationBean<>(
            new Enqueue(), "/taskqueues/enqueue");
    bean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return bean;
}
```

While Enqueue is:

```
public class Enqueue extends HttpServlet {

   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
                  HttpServletResponse response)
                  throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Add the task to the default queue.
        Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
        queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/testTaskQueue")
             .param("key", "54"));
        response.sendRedirect("/");
    }
}
```

Both throws the CallNotFoundException.

How can I make this work? What I did wrong?

Comment: Task Queues are implemented for GAE Standard which has some limitations. It might be that you are not able to work with Springboot, therefore I advise you to try [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/) which are the new equivalent for Task Queues and are implemented for GAE Flexible. You can also find some [samples here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/tasks).

Comment: Just adding to the answer from TasosZG, it appears that this error is caused for no using the standard environment as this other case [1] is reflecting and showing almost the same error as you posted. Even so you should consider using Cloud Tasks.

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354788/java-gae-task-queue-callnotfoundexception